# How to get one or multiple values from a cell and dump the rest of the cell using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, jupyter-notebook

In this database of movies, there’s this column called spoken languages. The data in the column looks like this

```
[{“iso_639_1”: “cn”, “name”: “\u5e7f\u5dde\u8bdd / \u5ee3\u5dde\u8a71”}, 
 {“iso_639_1”: “ja”, “name”: “\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e”}, 
 {“iso_639_1”: “zh”, “name”: “\u666e\u901a\u8bdd”}
]
```

I need to extract the language code, so I was thinking of using the string split function to extract the code between the quotes after this specific line ‘“iso_639_1”:’ and using that to clean the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary items are string representations you can first turn them into dictionaries again by applying `ast.literal_eval`, then you can simply extract the language code by getting the `iso_639_1` key:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

d = ['{"iso_639_1": "cn", "name": "\u5e7f\u5dde\u8bdd / \u5ee3\u5dde\u8a71"}', 
 '{"iso_639_1": "ja", "name": "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e"}', 
 '{"iso_639_1": "zh", "name": "\u666e\u901a\u8bdd"}'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['a'])
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(ast.literal_eval) #not needed if the values already exist as dicts in your df
df['lang'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x:x['iso_639_1'])
```

Output:

|  | a | lang |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | {'iso_639_1': 'cn', 'name': '广州话 / 廣州話'} | cn |
| 1 | {'iso_639_1': 'ja', 'name': '日本語'} | ja |
| 2 | {'iso_639_1': 'zh', 'name': '普通话'} | zh |

Comment: Well, creating a dataframe like that works, but if I have a dataframe already and try to use it it breaks.

Comment: Please update your question with a reproducible sample dataframe.